Where can I find math PhD opportunities scholarship?
I am looking for scholarships of math Phds, mainly Europe/US/Canada but I am open for good programs in Asia, Is there a kind of database for math PhDs ?

In Canada (and I assume the US) math PhDs are assumed to be funded. The pay isn't great but it will usually cover cost of living. Sometimes the pay is in return for working TA hours, and sometimes it's for working on a specific project.
Each institution may have additional scholarships for additional students. But you're best to find a supervisor who you're interested in and who has funding.
There is the NSERC CGS and PGS scholarships which would apply to math, but last I checked they are for either Canadian residents or people who have already completed a degree in Canada.

This is accurate for the US as well. One applies to the math PhD program through the online system of the university in question, and if you're admitted, 99% of the time you will receive full funding.

Just to be clear, Phds in Canada/Us are not free in the sense that you initially have to pay tuition fees but they are funded by working as TA ?

There is tuition, and then you are paid a stipend that vastly exceeded tuition. So you might get paid CAD $30k per year between TAing and research, and pay $6k in tuition. Some departments might also have tuition vouchers so you don't have to pay.

@user1149748, "full funding" isn't really accurate. You generally will get a TA which has duties attached; grading and holding study sections for elementary courses. It includes a modest stipend for living as well as paying the tuition. (US perspective). That is quite different from "full funding" which is rare. It isn't a scholarship, but a part-time "job".

@Buffy True but it's distinct from Undergraduate, where you pay tuition and have no income, apart from scholarships.
